# Angular 2 redux initial state relies on localStorage which can be set by query parameters

Tags: angular, redux

Angular 2 application with redux setup, I have to set up the application so users upon coming navigating back will load up their previous settings. I also have to set it up so users can link specific settings for the application using query parameters. The problem I have is that the initialization of the redux store gets the data from local storage before the subscription to the query parameters has a chance to do anything.

Observable with runs after getting both the settings needed to set query parameters (always together)

```
Observable.zip(this.accordionData$, this.apiSettings$).subscribe(data => {
  let accordionParam: string = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data[0]));
  let apiSettingsParam: string = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(data[1]));
  this._router.navigate([''], { queryParams: { scope: apiSettingsParam, accordion: accordionParam }, relativeTo: this._route })
});
```

Subscription to the query parameters that should set the state

```
this._route.queryParams.subscribe((params: Params) => {
  let scope = decodeURIComponent(params['scope']) !== 'undefined' ? decodeURIComponent(params['scope']): null;
  let accordion = decodeURIComponent(params['accordion']) !== 'undefined' ? decodeURIComponent(params['accordion']): null;
  if(scope){
    this.actions.updateAPISettings(JSON.parse(scope));
  }
  if(accordion){
    this.actions.updateAccordionData(JSON.parse(accordion));
  }
});
```

Example of the issue where the initial api settings get set.

```
const initialAPISettings = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('scope')) || {
  'Scope': {
    'CountryList': [0],
    'DesignationList': [],
    'CustomIndex': {}
  }
};
```

To clarify the bootstrapped module uses the `ngRedux.provideStore(store);` in the constructor and the bootstrapped component is where the subscription to the query parameters happens. Maybe I need to do the subscription in the module constructor before providing the store. That sort of feels like an anti pattern.

So my question boils down to how to wait to provide the store until query params have been checked and local storage has been set.

Comment: i might be completely off, as i am not sure i read your question correctly, but why dont you put your reading of localStorage into service, get data from that service at the same time when you read query params and once you resolve results - update the store with values?

Answer (score 0):

Your true initial state cannot have the async data, because it's not there from the get go.

You want to have an initial state that indicates that important data is still being fetched. For example `initialDataFetched: bool = false`. This would be part of your initial state, along with the data you requested as nulls (or whatever you prefer).

Then somewhere in your application you will start retrieving the data you need from local storage. This could but be triggered by a redux action or not.
Once the data is retreived, dispatch an action with the data as payload. The reducer handling the action would then merge the data into the store along with setting the flag `initialDataFetched` to true.

Meanwhile you can just not display whatever relies on the localStorage data and instead show loading state or nothing (if your async action is expected to be nearly instant).